# QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' is nullable

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with Firebase in Flutter

This is the code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tasks").snapshots(),
              builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot){
                if(!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
                return Expanded(
                  child: _buildList(snapshot.data)
                );
              }
            )
```

And the console tell me:

> Error: The argument type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' can't be assigned
> to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>' because
> 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' is nullable and 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'
> isn't. lib/main.dart:82
>
> - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'
>   ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-3.1.4/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
>   package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart:1
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>   child: _buildList(snapshot.data)

I can't understand the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshot.data` could be null, that means it is nullable. You already made sure it won't be `null` by adding an `if (snapshot.hasData)`, but dart doesn't know that. So in order to let dart know that you've made sure a nullable value is not null, you should add a null check operator (`!`):

```
_buildList(snapshot.data!);
```

This means you will get an error if `snapshot.data` is null, but in this case it won't be because you already checked before.